# How to get Embedded PHP working in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in PHP and I am trying to embed PHP in HTML as that is how I am going to need it in my project. This one is a very simple code saved as `Trial.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trial Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello, today is <?php echo "a great day!"; ?>.
</body>
</html>
```

When I load this page from server (I am running Apache Tomcat 7 locally), Only the HTML part is getting displayed and the PHP part is not. What am I missing? Do I need to include anything else or am I taking a completely wrong approach for this?

Comment: Try saving as `trial.php`

Comment: make sure the file extension ends in .php and make sure you're actually running the file from the server and not running the file itself

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Tomcat?

Comment: @TZHX I was working on Angular where I was using the same server for some temporary basic things. I made a mistake of using the same one without considering PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your file as .php and run it on a server with php installed on it.

check [XAMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to install a local server

EDIT

Just saw that you're running Tomcat, just make sure php is installed, that your server is running, you're running your file from the server And your file is save as .php

Answer (score 3):

Rename "Trial.html" to "Trial.php" this is essential when you try to run php code.

Answer (score 1):

You change file name from trial.html to trial.php